# Python: finding the +100th prime number

Tags: python, numbers, primes

I have a weird problem with my program.
When n<=100 it works just fine.
However when it comes to bigger numbers(such as n=121) it keeps showing me this message:

```
File "my_code.py2", line 24, in 
    print k[int(n)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
k=[]
z=[]
a=0
k.append(1)
k.append(2)
k.append(3)
n=raw_input()
while n!="END" and int(n)>0 and int(n)%100000==int(n):              
    for x in xrange(3,7919,2): 
        for i in xrange(3,x,2):      
            if x%i!=0:
                a=1
            else:
                a=0
                break
        if a==1:
            k.append(x)
        if len(k)==int(n):
            break          
    print k[int(n)]
    n=raw_input()
```

Can you help me???

Comment: It doesn't "work just fine" for me -- at least not on inputs of 5,10,50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an off-by-one error.  Python uses zero based-indexing, so to get the 121st element you would want to access your list at `k[120]`.

By the way, 1 is not a prime number.

---

*edit:*  Rather than fix up other issues with the code that you've mention in the comments, might I suggest a better algorithm?  Rather than checking for divisors, the [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is the usual way of listing all primes below a bound.  It's easy to implement and should be faster than your current method with nested loops.

Comment: Agreed. However, it doesn't matter which is the k[0] because I will never ask for it. I have another major problem. Try this yourself. If I press a big number(such as 25 or something) without pressing first the number 1,2 or 3 it says: File "my_code.py2", line 24, in 
    print k[int(n)]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

This is because you break the loop when `len(k) == int(n)` and then access `k[int(n)]`. Since python uses `0` based indexing, when the list length is equal to `n`, the last index you can access is `n-1`.

As you add 1 to the list, and 1 is not a prime, every other prime in the list will have their actual index.

I.e 2 is at index 1, and 2 is the first prime.
    3 is at index 2, and 3 is the second prime.

So, the solution is to change `len(k) == int(n)` to `len(k) == int(n) + 1`.

NOTE: There is an another issue with your program. When ever the statements inside the outer loop get excuted. It keeps adding elements to `k` unnecessarily. So, what i suggest is first calculate all the primes upto a certain limit. And then just query that list. Don't repeatedly calculate all the primes from the beginning.

```
k=[]
z=[]
a=0

k.append(1)
k.append(2)
k.append(3)

for x in xrange(3,7919,2): 
    for i in xrange(3,x,2):      
        if x%i!=0:
            a=1
        else:
            a=0
            break
    if a==1:
        k.append(x)

n = raw_input()
while n!="END" and int(n)>0 and int(n) < len(k):                      
    print k[int(n)]
    n = raw_input()
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I solve one of my major problems. However now I have another problem... When it comes to n>100 it says wrong answer...

Comment: Did you see the edited version of my answer. 
The problem with your earlier version is this. Say you asked for 4th prime at the first time. After that iteration 
k will be [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]. When you query for another prime, say 10th, at the second iteration of the while loop, it will add next primes to the existing list. So the list will now be [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]. That's why you are getting the wrong answer. Either you have to clear the k at every iteration. Or just compute once as in my solution and then only query it. :-)